# Can we use the extended euclidian algorithm to simplify factorization process of two products of large prime numbers with one common factor?

Tags: prime-factoring

We have two products of prime numbers with a large number of digits, so we don t have enough computing power to find its factors.
The products have one common prime factor.
Can we use the extended euclidian algorithm for finding GCD to simplify factorization process and make it computationally possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is not yet a programming question. Currently it is a number theory / computation theory question.

Comment: Agreed with Raymond. This is off topic.

Comment: Since the tag "prime factorization" exists, this is not off topic. The answer is strongly connected with programming, because it has to do with an algorithm useful to programmers who mess with encryption implementations. If there is an answer, it maybe won t help only me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course. Suppose the first "large product of prime factors" is 3 × 7 = 21 and the second "large product of prime factors" is 5 × 7 = 35. Then the GCD of 21 and 35 is 7, which is a factor of both "large products of prime factors." You don't even need the extended algorithm, a simple GCD is sufficient.

But this isn't very useful, because you seldom have two large semi-primes that share a common factor.